# JDA Send message in Cyrillic results in a bunch of gibberish

Tags: discord-jda

```java
@Override
    public void onGuildMemberJoin(@NotNull GuildMemberJoinEvent event) {
        TextChannel textChannel = event.getGuild().getTextChannelsByName("channel-name", true).getFirst();
        String userMention = event.getMember().getAsMention();

        String greeting = String.format("Привет, %s. Зайди в канал #roles.", userMention);
        textChannel.sendMessage(greeting).queue();
    }
}
```

That is my code. I am a beginner only, but I suspect there might be a problem with encoding.

I searched through JDA documentation and didn't find much help. What is the problem here?

Comment: This is pretty much what the bot sents, if it provides any value:

ÐŸÑ€Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ‚, @test. Ð—Ð°Ð¹Ð´Ð¸ Ð² ÐºÐ°Ð½Ð°Ð» #roles Ð¸ Ð½Ð°Ð¶Ð¼Ð¸ Ð½Ð° Ñ€ÐµÐ°ÐºÑ†Ð¸ÑŽ Ð¾Ð³Ð¾Ð½ÑŒ.
Ð¢Ñ‹ Ð¿Ð¾Ð»ÑƒÑ‡Ð¸ÑˆÑŒ Ñ€Ð¾Ð»ÑŒ Ð½Ð° Ñ�ÐµÑ€Ð²ÐµÑ€ Ð¸ Ñ�Ð¼Ð¾Ð¶ÐµÑˆÑŒ Ð·Ð°Ñ…Ð¾Ð´Ð¸Ñ‚ÑŒ Ð² Ð³Ð¾Ð»Ð¾Ñ�Ð¾Ð²Ñ‹Ðµ ÐºÐ°Ð½Ð°Ð»Ñ‹.

The message is longer, because that is the actual message I need to send, not the message provided as an example.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it, turns out you have this thing called Locale.
If you need to process input of different languages it is a best practice to change the defaultLocale.

```java
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.of("ru", "RU")); // Locale.of("lang", "country")
    }
}
```